# Jquery flexigrid select check box by selecting the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
$("#rfqDetails").flexigrid({
        dataType: 'json',
        colModel: [
         { display: 'checkbox', name: '', width: 30, align: 'center' },
         { display: 'RfqNo', name: 'RfqNo', width: 80, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
         { display: 'PreferredSupplier', name: 'PreferredSupplier', width: 100, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
         { display: 'Status', name: 'Status', width: 80, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
         { display: 'Company', name: 'Company', width: 80, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
         { display: 'Edit', name: '', width: 80, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
         { display: 'View', name: '', width: 80, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
        ],
        title: "RFQ Summary",
        height: 320,
        showToggleBtn: false,
        singleSelect: false,
        resizable: false
    });


$('#rfqDetails').click(function ()
{
    var selected = $('#rfqDetails .trSelected td:eq(0)');

    $(selected).each(function ()
    {
        selected.attr('checked', 'checked')
    });
});
```

The above is my code for flexigrid. In the first column I have the checkbox  by selecting the row I have to select the checkbox and when deselecting the row the checkbox has to deselect.

Comment: Please show the html part.

Comment: <table id="rfqDetails"></table>

Comment: It is an asp.net mvc app